# What Household Items can be used to Clean Motherboards

Tags: cleaning, chemicals

I have a motherboard that require deep cleaning (its not just the dust we are talking about). I have seen over the youtube that people are using WD-40 and brake fluid to washaway the contaminants from the motherboard. So I went on and did a little search and in turns out that WD-40 can also dissolve the protective film on the motherboard and can leave lubricant film.

The second option is to use iso-propyl alcohol but that also might not clean the contaminants well. Is there better option?

---

Based on the answers the following protocol for deep cleaning the motherboard might be desirable:

- Step 1: Vacuuming and airblowing to remove obvious dirt
- Step 2: Spraying cleaning solvents such as brake fluid to wash away
  more clinging contaminants (nicotine, insect remains and other sticky
  substance)
- Step 3: Final pass of wipe cleaning risers, rams, graphics card slots
  using cotton pads immersed in 70% isopropyl alcohol (99% is better!)

Comment: This may have been better at [electronics.se] since they tend to have EEs haunting the place as opposed to the electricians who haunt this place. You've attracted a couple of good answers here, so this is just a thought for future reference.

Comment: Also, what are you trying to accomplish by cleaning the mobo? Do you just want to remove general grossness? Do you want it to look spectacular under lights in your l33t plexiglass case? Are you having actual issues getting the computer to run? If the machine works and you're not trying to put it on display, I'd be tempted to knock off the big chunks (as it were) and leave the rest alone.

Comment: @FreeMan I am accomplishing to remove roaches and other insects related smell and their remains ( this is actually an 2011 imac which I had kept in my attic long time back) recovered and saw it was infested. Now I am doing a full cleanup of the wonderful machine.

Comment: @J... I mentioned its insects related cleaning as roaches and their remains were all over the imac. I should have mentioned it in the question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about cleaning electronics, not about [diy.se]. Please see the [help/on-topic] for more information.

Comment: I think people giving you "WD-40" and "brake fluid" advice are trolling you.  Either that, or they failed to mentally connect their board failure a month later to their cleaning techniques.  WD-40 is a product you have no reason to own unless you run a Titan missile museum. It's for polishing missiles. For anything else you would do with it, there are better products.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plain old rubbing alcohol would be a decent option for flushing cigarette smoke residue without affecting the solder mask layer of the mobo pcb like naptha can, or harming components like acetone can. spray it wet with alcohol,keep spraying until the runoff is not gross, then go over it with a soft toothbrush or other such brush, then hit it again with an overspray to rinse. Let it dry overnight in front of a fan before use.

If you can't find isopropyl right now, you can use red heet or strong ethyl alcohol. A powered general purpose detergent should also work, like the bags they sell in the mexican section of your grocery store, but will take more elbow grease than nicotine-dissolving alcohol would.

Comment: Can ethanol be used on plastic parts as well without worrying about any issues, such as computer fans and rams etc? Also what general purpose detergent are you talking about? Tide powder etc? wont water effect the motherboard?

Comment: Ethanol is safe to use on plastics, components, etc. mind the pc speaker/buzzer if there is one, you don't want to fill it. Example detergent brands include roma (my fav) and foca. Water won't hurt the mobo so long as it's un-powered while wet. fwiw, former A+ certified PC tech with ~5 years working pc maintenance+repair and we used alcohol, water, windex, even brake cleaner... Acetone and other petroleum distillates are to be avoided.

Comment: Also, make sure you discharge the capacitors by unplugging and turning on the computer.You should see the fan start to spin but that is it.

Comment: While I guess that answers my concernes. Isnt brake cleaner gonna dissolve plastic also hamper the contact in the pc fan? I want to clean the fans also as there is foul smell of insects when they turn. Someone suggested WD-40 but again its a dust magnet and not recommended.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean yes, I learned that lesson the hard way when I touched the unplugged power supply that I opened to remove the dust. Got the shock from the big capacitor and it was significant. +1 for the advice.

Comment: you might find the story and comments on [this article](https://hackaday.com/2020/04/29/cheap-alternative-solvents-for-pcb-cleaning/) informative. Fans can be cleaned with anything i suggested; remove the rubber axle gasket, pry out the rotor (might need to remove a retaining clip), and clean the stator with a brush. dry, re-assemble. add a drop of 3in1 if needed. Brake cleaner's have different formulations, so check the packaging, but most should be ethanol-based.

Comment: @dandavis thanks a lot for the pro tip! yes different vendors of brake fluid consists of different blends. I shall look for ethanol-based as I really need to clean the motherboard properly.

Comment: Rubbing alcohol is a good answer, but keep in mind that "70% isopropol" also means "30% water". If you can get 90%, it would evaporate more quickly.

Comment: @spuck yes, I am aiming for 90% isopropol alcohol but its hard to get. All the convenient stores and pharmacies store rubbing alcohol with is 70%

Comment: @gfdsal: you can easily turn 70% into 99% with table salt. just add a bunch to the bottle and shake. Pure alcohol will float on top of the brine. baste/siphon it from the top, or turn the bottle upside-down, loosen the cap slightly and squeeze until the salt water is pushed out the bottom, leaving only alcohol. science is fun. Only works with isopropyl, other alcohols absorb salt...

Answer (score 4):

...start with re-evaluating your perception that it "needs cleaned." Or stop smoking around your computer.

As a computer professional, I have pretty much never cleaned a motherboard. Occasionally vacuumed out dust bunnies, but I prefer to locate computers where dust bunnies are less likely to accumulate in them. I have occasionally replaced computers that users spilled things into, and if that (or smoking) is the problem, that is the path to take, not "cleaning" which will be a large time investment for unpredictable results.

What cleaners are suitable is dependent on what the factory that built it chose for a cleaning process, such that they made the components compatible with that solvent. In some modern low VOC processes soap and water and a through rinse / dry is entirely suitable. In the bad old days Freon was a common choice...

Comment: Amazing opening of the answer. I should indeed quit smoking. Allright, it was infested with roaches when I opened it (dont judge me) now mere vacuuming wont do. If it was ordinary tool I would have pressure washed it and even added disinfectant just to be sure :) For the gaming motherboard I want to ensure it is properly catered to in terms of cleaning. I did not understand what is VOC processes soap? Shouldnt soap and water not be used at all? this causes rust. The motherboard is from 2011 with i7 so pretty modern.

Comment: @gfdsal The only metal parts of your mobo that you would need to worry about rusting are the metal contacts and they should all be gold-plated so they'll never corrode. Some (but not all) mobos also have metal plating around the mounting holes to ground the board to the chassis. A few minutes of soaking and light scrubbing with a gentle scrubber (nylon bristles, not metal of any sort) and a thorough drying shouldn't cause any harm.

Comment: @FreeMan alright, few minutes of soaking in soapy water, if thats what you meant right?

Comment: @gfdsal yes, sorry, I missed "in soapy water".

Comment: Did you just say "from 2011, so pretty modern"?

Comment: 9 years old, smoke coated and roach infested - yup, as a professional I'd bin it. Not remotely worth spending time on. Probably wastes a ton of power compared to a modern computer of equivalent or better processing power. Simply not smoking around your computer would be sufficient for the computer's health, if you choose to continue to smoke despite what it does to your health. At this point I refuse to have anything to do with a computer that's been smoked around - they are beyond nasty, even without roaches. The deposits impair cooling as well as smelling awful.

Comment: @Ecnerwal its an 2011 imac. I assume you might not bin it :-) I totally agree with you the deposits smell awful and that is why I want to deep clean.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica well according to moore's law, technology has quite slowely progressed. Its i7 model from 2011 and we are still seeing new releases of i7 based computers.